# How to convert a pdf into a canvas and that canvas to an image?

Tags: javascript, image, pdf, canvas, pdf.js

I have two parts of the problem, one taking a pdf and putting it on canvas which I have been able to solve using pdf.js and the second part of the problem is to convert that canvas to an image.

For any other canvas, I have been able to convert that into an image using canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'). But when I am working with a PDF as a canvas, I am getting a white image.

Does anybody have a pdf in canvas for which they can try whether the canvas is getting converted to an image or not? Or if anybody else has faced this issue and fixed it someway?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you looking for a pdf? Please refer to [ask].

Comment: No, I want to render a PDF in VR but I can't seem to be able to do it. So, I want to convert the whole PDF to a canvas and then to an image

Comment: Your question currently asks `Does anybody have a pdf in canvas for which they can try whether the canvas is getting converted to an image or not?` - if this is not a key part of your question, I recommend removing it, since it will confuse those who try to answer it.

Comment: My recommendation would be to separate the functions of displaying the PDF and converting it to an image.

Comment: @sid3007 did you find a solution to this? If yes, please post as i am having same issue. Using canvas.toDataURL() produces same image regardless of the pdf inputted